# Scripted Fields for if/else condition in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, kibana-4

I have some numeric fields in elasticsearch, I have to implement some logic for which I need to create some scripted fields. I am new to kibana 4's scripted fields feature, so I need some help regarding a basic format that could be used for writing a basic if else condition in scripted fields.

Detailed explanation:
I have a number field `x` in elasticsearch, I need to create two scripted fields `f1` and `f2` such that,

```
if x==0
  f1 = 1  and  f2 = 0
else
  f1 = 0  and  f2 = 1
```

Just need the correct syntax to do this in Kibana 4's scripted fields feature.
Also tell if this can't be done. 
For more information on scripted fields refer : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a scripted field, you go into the `Settings` for the index and click on the `Scripted Fields` tab.  Hit `Add Scripted Field`.

In your case, you will enter `f1` as the Name and `doc['x'].value == 0 ? 1 : 0` as the Script.  You'll then add a second scripted field with `f2` as the Name and `doc['x'].value != 0 ? 1 : 0` as the script.

The `?:` is the ternary operator and works like in most languages -- it evaluates the condition before the `?` and if the value is `true` the expression has the value of whatever is after the `?` and if it's false, it has the value of whatever is after the `:`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But instead of **doc['x']**, I used **doc['x'].value** and it worked.

Comment: If in case i want this structure
        doc["x"].value=="*Vol" ?1:0

Will this work?